# Nginx Not Showing Static Content on Localhost

Tags: nginx

I'm working on creating a basic Nginx server to show a static HTML webpage (for now) and I am having an issue viewing my content.  I've followed the tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts), by creating a new server block, named `quake.dev`.  I have removed the symlink to the `default` server block in `/etc/sites-enabled/default` and created the symlink between `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` for `quake.dev`

**My nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**quake.dev**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/quake.dev/html/;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name quake.dev www.quake.dev;

    location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        allow 192.168.0.1/24;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I then added `quake.dev` to my `/etc/hosts` file:

**hosts**

```
#127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1       quake.dev
127.0.1.1       wintermute

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

After restarting both nginx and the networking service, I load `quake.dev` into Chrome and it returns `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.  Is there anything anyone can think of?  I've been up and down this issue for days now.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: turned out there was a broken symlink between sites-enabled and sites-available.  *places dunce cap on head*